# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException when mocking java.nio.ByteBuffer class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock ByteBuffer class in java.nio with Mockito for testing in JUnit. I get a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

My code looks like -

```
class TestClass {

    @Mock
    private ByteBuffer byteBuffer

     @Before
     public void setup() {
         Mockito.when(byteBuffer.array()).thenReturn("some-string".getBytes()); //this line throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
     }
}
```

How differently should I mock the array method for this to work? I am using Java 8.

Comment: It is stated in the javadoc that `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown if this buffer is not backed by an accessible array. You should assign a not null buffer for it.

Comment: Why mock it? Just create it by wrapping the array returned by that `getBytes`.

Comment: @Alex if I am mocking the object, how do I assign a not null buffer to it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like in the comment from [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) you don't need to mock this class or classes that are easily composed from primitives like `byte []`.

There are a number of different [test doubles](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) (fakes, spies etc.) apart from mocks and this is a better case for a fake than a mock.

Just use:

```
byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("some-string".getBytes());
```

Comment: Yes that made sense. lesson learned - do not over-mock  objects.

Answer (score 4):

You get a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` because `ByteBuffer.array()` is a final method. Therefore it is not mocked by Mockito. This means that

```
Mockito.when(byteBuffer.array()).thenReturn("some-string".getBytes());
```

calls the real method which throws the exception.

Comment: This explanation helps understanding the root cause.